# Conservation of Energy in Blue Shift

Tags: visible-light, frequency, doppler-effect, equivalence-principle

Imagine light coming down and hitting a neutron star. It light is blue-shifted. I know that energy/mass is conserved and that the energy to blue-shift it comes from the gravitational field, but how is energy conserved in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blue shift is actually necessary to conserve energy. The photon has energy, and therefore has potential energy relative to the neutron star. It loses gravitational energy as it approaches the neutron star, and it gains energy in the form of blue shift. Indeed, to the first order in GR, the change in energy of a photon is equal to the change in gravitational potential.